# BLE113 Bluetooth 4.0 module with CR2025 3v battery power supply

Tags: power, bluetooth, modulation, bluetooth-low-energy

A question regarding the power supply of a BLE113 Bluetooth 4.0 module: I am attempting to order several bluetooth modules, but the main concern is the power supply. Since I am new in the field of all sorts of modules and electronics, what is the best way in which can I connect a bluetooth module to a power supply such as CR2025 3V?

The main idea is to connect the mentioned bluetooth 4.0 module to an Apple iOS application.

Comment: The datasheet of the BLE113 module specifies that it can be powered directly from a coin cell, I would just buy a coin cell holder and solder wires from the holder the the BLE113 module. You might want to include an ON/OFF switch as well.

Comment: The peak currents of BLE would suggest you use at least CR2032.  Smaller batteries supple less peak currents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main concern with any wireless module on a low-performance power supply is to design in very heavy decoupling. Coin cells in particular - excluding recheargable lithium ion type (which are very rare) - have internal resistance up to about 100 ohms, so you will not be able to draw more than a couple of milliamps from them. As your BLE113 module is specified to draw up to 18mA, this will significantly reduce your battery lifetime or even pull the battery flat . The solution for this is (obviously) to use a big energy reserve in the form of an aluminum electrolytic capacitor of enough capacity to deliver all the energy needed for a single transmission.

Then obviously also make sure your average power consumption does not exceed what the battery can deliver (efficiently): power down the wireless radio as much as you can as well as your microcontroller or whatever other active devices you have in your application.

Comment: This is probably worth posting in your answer http://www.batterystore.com/Renata/RENpdf/RCR2025.pdf

Comment: But the real questions is, what is the best way to connect the Bluetooth module to a power supply? Should I achieve this via usual wires directly or do I need a third-party or middle man in this?

Comment: dsafa: Bluegiga's [website](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble113-bluetooth--smart-module/) says specifically that you can connect their modules directly to a coin cell. You don't need anything but some kind of energy buffering in between, or possibly setting some power reduction registers like bobh suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BlueGiga's dev tools, you can aid in power reduction by limiting the transmit power in the hardware.xml file. 0 dBm draws 15 ma. peak (typical BLE112). Your use case may allow lower tx power.

The older BLE112 allowed +3dBm output which exceeded the capacity of a cr2032.